# Understanding of a Batch

Tags: ksh, cat

Which of those lines are correct? I work step by step.

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
```

I didn't find any correct explanations about the `-ne` but I understood that this line check if the last preformed action is a success.

```
ksh $PROC/reg.sh 2>&1 | tee $REG
```

`ksh` means that I'll use a korn shell that is reg.sh situated into PROC, 2>&1 redirects stderr into a not specified file, and redirects sterr to stdout. (I don't really understand what it does and I don't get what is the role of `| tee $REG`)

```
cat $REG >> $DD_LIBEDIT/log.$DATE
```

`cat` is used to concatanate, but in this line their is only one file, does it mean that REG is concatanate into log?

```
This.$DATE (DATE=`date +%Y%m%d)
```

does it add the DATE to the log?

This is just a few part of the Batch, I tried to select the ones where I coudln't understand the meaning, even after many researches.

Comment: First thing you should do is learn to read `man` pages. Try `man [` e.g. for the first question.

Comment: `man bash` might be usefull, it'll explain all about `>&` `|` `>>` `<<` and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man page of your shell will usually help. Lets take your first example.

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
```

On my system `man ksh` says:

```
   if list ;then list [ ;elif list ;then list ] ... [ ;else list ] ;fi
          The list following if is executed and, if it returns a zero exit  sta‐
          tus,  the  list  following the first then is executed.  Otherwise, the
          list following elif is executed and, if its value is  zero,  the  list
          following  the  next  then  is executed.  Failing each successive elif
          list, the else list is executed.  If the if  list  has  non-zero  exit
          status  and  there is no else list, then the if command returns a zero
          exit status.
```

Especially this means between `if` and `then` there is a "list", i.e. a command which gets executed.

The actual command of the list is `[`. This is both a command and a shell builtin:

```
$ type -a [  
[ is a shell builtin
[ is /usr/bin/[
```

Use `man [` for the command and `man ksh` for the builtin. (For bash `help [` would give you details of the builtin, too.)

Most of the time it does not matter whether we are talking about the command or the builtin. `man [` now says:

```
   INTEGER1 -ne INTEGER2
          INTEGER1 is not equal to INTEGER2
```

In your case it will compare the value of the variable `$?` with zero.
Again have a look at `man ksh`:

```
   The following parameters are automatically set by the shell:
          ?      The decimal value returned by the last executed command.
```

A return value of zero usually means everything is fine. (But check the man page of the particular command to make sure.)

Therefore `if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then` will simply check if an error occured in the previous command.

---

The `cat` command will read all files and output them to standard out. You can then use your shell to redirect this to a file. Again have a look at `man ksh`:

```
   >>word        Use  file  word  as  standard output.  If the file exists, then
                 output is appended to it (by first seeking to the end-of-file);
                 otherwise, the file is created.
```

Comment: Thank's a lot, I'm sorry I didn't even know this command. I'll try to use it as much as possible.